# Is it possible to reverse a concatenated/? string. making it into a single (changed) variable

Tags: php, variables, mysqli, reverse, string-concatenation

I split this string ($messageText) using a formula like this:

```
list($msgat, $message) = explode("!", "$messageText", 2);
```

selecting a row from my database:

with this:

```
$sql = "SELECT verse FROM ".$datatable." WHERE book LIKE '%".$message."'";
```

I need to come up with a way to make this: (which works, on a page echoing)

```
 echo " " . $row["book"].  " " . $row["verse"]. "<br>";
```

something back into a single string: something like this I've been trying.

```
$answer =  " . $row["verse"]. "
```

thus, I would be able to use the original but changed, variable elsewhere.

I have tried various methods, trying to concoct a solution...

```
$answer =   $row["verse"] ;
```

etc etc... I am stumped... it is probably right before me I just can't find it.

Comment: Why not just `$answer = " " . $row["book"].  " " . $row["verse"];`?

Comment: There's no benefit quoting here: `"$messageText"`, this is likely the same as `$messageText` (assuming it is a string).

Comment: I've read this a dozen times, and I still don't understand the question.

Comment: @Nick  thats what i thought, it doesn't work though.. exactly like you posted.  One reason why i'm stumped.  Progrock true enough, i guess its just a habit.  Progrock I'm stumped as to why something like what Nick Suggests _does not work_ in this scenario?  Thanks for the reply. :)

Comment: @GarrettKrosschell what error you are getting. on using what nick suggested...

Comment: Just a blank page.  I have error_reporting(1).  not sure where else I can determine the issue.  ?

Comment: echo  $answer = " " . $row["book"]. " " . $row["verse"];

Comment: have you echo it?

Comment: if i just echo " " . $row["book"].  " " . $row["verse"].;  it Will show on my page.
i need to make that as a single Variable though.  hence, why i am trying to get that "echo" result put into a string called $answer.  Thank you.

Comment: i guess in simplest terms of explaining (my poor interpretation), would be:  im trying to make this: $row["verse"]  into: $answer.

Comment: @GarrettKrosschell check the answer I think you are making any mistake while writing your code. 
just copy paste the code as it is.
then show us your full code in case of error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$answer = " " . $row["book"]. " " . $row["verse"]; //this will store value into single variable answer
echo $answer; // use this if you want to display the result on the page.
```

this will definitely work if not show us the error so that we can resolve it.

Comment: exactly what i have been trying. it still displays a blank page, although it WILL 'Echo' it, just does not want to echo the $answer (string).. i will look for the issue some more.  logs, etc. and post back.. Thank you! :)

Comment: don't use echo $answer from the above code if you do not want to echo it.

Comment: Thank you!  I believe i found the issue.. :/ 
i wish i could just delete this Question now.. ?
it was as you suggested, A "typo" (a closing bracket was missing)
Any ways.. newb mistake. thanks for your patience. :)

Comment: @GarrettKrosschell you cannot close the question on StackOverflow because other people have wasted their time on it. you need to approve the answer.